# NelmioApiDocBundle Post Request with Json body

Tags: symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm using symfony 2.6.1,
I'm using the FosRestApiBundle and I want to document it, so I tried to NelmioApiDocBundle, the problem is that in post requests, I can't set the body of the post request, is there any solution to this problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the problem with NelmioApiDocBundle or is your problem with FosRestApiBundle post requests? Can you please add more information for your problem.

Comment: question is bit unclear, please add some code along with @ApiDoc() of the method you are trying to document.

Comment: My problem is with the documentation, i want to have a field to set the body,thank you

Comment: I am having a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803820/symfony-nelmioapidocbundle-swagger-ui-php-annotations-cannot-post-json-body I posted an issue on github but have not heard anything yet